# What is the maven matcher for all packages?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I would like to exclude the necessity of having `package-info` files in every of our packages. My defined path is ignored, so probably it is wrong. Please what is the correct expression for matching all packages under `com.*` ?

```
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.ruleKey>squid:S1228</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.ruleKey>
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey>com/**</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey>
```

Comment: The rule S2118 checks that a `package-info.java` is included in yuor project, so that there is a javadoc documentation of the package you are building. The rule does not check packages you are using in your project. So, for what reason do you want to exclude packages starting with `com.???`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule S2118 is a special case since issues are not reported on files. They used to be reported on folders, but with recent versions of SonarQube we removed the ability to report issues on folders so those issues will be reported at project level.

In any case (old or new behavior) it is not possible to use issue exclusion by path pattern for such issues (it only works for file level issues).

So you can only apply the rule on your entire project, or disable it.

Comment: Is there any way how could I disable it in pom.xml or parameter to sonar maven goal?

Answer (score 0):

The expression should be `com/**/*`.

Comment: This is not for all files?

Comment: @Mejmo I might misunderstood your question (see my comment to your question, please)

Answer (score 0):

[Julien H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609837/4764903) explains why it is impossible to use `sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria` to ignore S2118.

However, another option is to use `sonar.issue.enforce.multicriteria` with a path pattern that will never match a path in your project, like `SONARQUBE_RULE_DISABLED`.  `sonar.issue.enforce.multicriteria` configures the rule to run *only* on matching paths - and by using a path it can never match, the rule is effectively disabled.  (Tested on SonarQube 8.9, YMMV)